# Auto send form (JSP) and load page in iframe

Tags: forms, jsp, post

I have a page (jsp) with a form and a submit button. After clicking the button the form data is posted to another JSP that creates the output (a table with links).

My problem is, I need to do this AUTOMATIC, I can fill the form via url GET thats not the problem but how can I force the post to that other page without clicking a button. I want to include the result (table with links) on another page (with php or just iframe) so the result has to be generated when the page is opened.

I CAN NOT change any of the JSP pages, they are part of a closed system which I can't change.

Thanks...